# Using enums in Django with error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models'

Tags: python, django

I am trying to use enums in my unit tests but I'm getting an error when I try to import them.
An excerpt from `models.py`:

```
class SeekingConstants:
    MEN = 'Men'
    WOMEN = 'Women'
    BOTH_MEN_AND_WOMEN = 'Both men and women'
```

An excerpt from `test_user_api.py`:

```
from models import SeekingConstants
...
def test_update_user_seeking_choice(self):
    """Part 1: Update the seeking choice from nothing"""
    payload = {
        'email': 'test@example.com',
        'seeking_choice': SeekingConstants.WOMEN
    }

    res = self.client.patch(ME_URL, payload)

    self.user.refresh_from_db()
    self.assertEqual(self.user.email, payload['email'])
    self.assertTrue(self.user.seeking_choice, payload['seeking_choice'])
    self.assertEqual(res.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)

    """Part 2: Update an existing seeking choice"""

    new_payload = {
        'email': 'test@example.com',
        'seeking_choice': SeekingConstants.BOTH_MEN_AND_WOMEN
    }

    res = self.client.patch(ME_URL, new_payload)

    self.user.refresh_from_db()
    self.assertEqual(self.user.email, payload['email'])
    self.assertTrue(self.user.seeking_choice, payload['seeking_choice'])
    self.assertEqual(res.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

[image: My project directory]

I'm not sure why I can't import this enum or how I should import this enum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to your screenshot:

```
from ..models import SeekingConstants
```